# как прочитать файл csv?

Tags: php, строки, csv

Есть php запрос в базу данных, обычная вставка `INSER INTO table (name, password) VALUES (:name, :password);`. Но данные подставляются из csv файла: `$file = file("csv.file")`. Потом делаю explode, и выбираю ячейки из массива. Но в итоге если вывести `echo "name: $file[0]";`, то получится: `name: "admin"`, как сделать что бы было `name: admin` ?

Comment: А вы не `explode` делайте, а [`fgetcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php)

Comment: либо натравите на $file str-getcsv https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: Спасибо большое, поставьте как ответ, я приму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для парсинга CSV есть функции [`fgetcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php) и [`str_getcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.str-getcsv.php).